# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't boot after kernel update

Tags: boot, kernel, updates

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on my computer:

Intel i7-11700,
ASUS PRIME B560M-A,
32GB RAM,
NVMe drive WD 1TB

There was several kernel updates since my first installation. But last booting kernel is 5.11.0-44-generic. Later installed kernel 5.13.0-27-generic nor 5.13.0-28-generic doesn't work.

When started via rescue mode with safe graphics resolution it boots. So probably the graphics is the issue.

I have also tried to boot Ubuntu 21.10 - no success

Thank you for help

Comment: Im using 5.13.0-28-generic so I don't think its the kernel. Try live Ubuntu and check your disk. You can try repair from live CD/USB.

Comment: What make/model video card? What version driver? Also show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: Integrated graphics ie. UHD Graphics 750. Bios version 1203. In new kernel module i915 doesn't detect the graphics. I also tried newest kernel via mainline - the same result.